# Shopify script_tag API - how to pass the variable?

Tags: javascript, php, api, shopify

I have some javascript code in my ShopifyApp which I'm adding to the ShopifyShop using script_tag API:

```
$response = $client->request(
'POST',
"https://{$store}/admin/script_tags.json",
[
    'headers' => [
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => $access_token
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'script_tag' => [
            "event" => "onload",
            "src" => $scriptUrl
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Script:

```
var _smid = 'someValue';
(function(a,b,c,d,e) {...})
```

My problem is that I need to pass var _smid there which is different per App instalation (generated server side) - is there any way to do it or maybe some other way to actually pass script as variable from php and not as url to .js file?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script tag to do a callback to an App Proxy. That way, your App gets the store name, and any other data you need to pass to it.